# .NET BoxApi.V2 timeout when uploading

Tags: api, timeout, box, createfile

In .NET I'm using the BoxApi.V2 to upload files to box.com.

Using BoxManager.CreateFile for big files (>90 mb) results in the following errors :
"The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation"
"The underlying connection has been closed"

Small files: no problem.
I can't seem to configure timeout anywhere in this API....

The exception occurs in the following location:
*BoxApi.V2.BoxRestClientBase.Try(IRestRequest request, HttpStatusCode lastResponse) in BoxApi.V2.BoxManager.WriteFile(IRestRequest request)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pingpath command I found out that my uploaded files took a major detour.

Sending them from our Paris office, they were forwarded to a server somewhere at the American west coast.

The target location being too remote is causing the time out, as was confirmed later by the BOX helpdesk.

The exact command is:

```
pathping ftp.box.com
```

Comment: Cheers mate, very helpful.